# R: extracting information from verbose output in nlme fit

Tags: r, output, mixed-models, nlme

```
library(nlme)
fm2 <- nlme(height ~ SSasymp(age, Asym, R0, lrc),
            data = Loblolly,
            fixed = Asym + R0 + lrc ~ 1,
            random = Asym ~ 1,
            start = c(Asym = 103, R0 = -10, lrc = -8), verbose = TRUE)

**Iteration 1
LME step: Loglik: -115.9653, nlminb iterations: 1
reStruct  parameters:
     Seed 
-6.000592 
Error in nlme.formula(height ~ SSasymp(age, Asym, R0, lrc), data = Loblolly,  : 
  step halving factor reduced below minimum in PNLS step
```

In this example, I fussed with the starting values a bit so the algorithm did not converge. However, I am interested in extracting the log-likelihood value, -115.9653 from the verbose output. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you can grab a string by using `out <- capture.output(try(fm2 <- nlme(height ... ` and then try to parse...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only have a manual solution for you:

set browsing on error:

```
options(error = recover)
```

Run your code and select the deepest frame. You should end up in the environment of the function that throws the error. You can access the likelihood with:

```
nlmeFit$logLik
```

and assign it to the global environment with:

```
LL <<- nlmeFit$logLik
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there an automatic way to store the verbose output in some way? Or would I have to do this manually?

Comment: you can include the commands to the browser (e.g."2" and "Q") in your script. This is very quick and dirty obviously, but for debugging that should do.

Comment: How exactly would I include those into my script? My goal is to automate fitting a bunch of different `nlme` functions. For those that have an error, I would like to automatically store the verbose output into, say, a list object.

Comment: In that case I would use `try()`, as user20650 suggested. You might want to edit your question or start a new one with a minimum example for what you are asking.

Comment: That stored the error message but not the verbose output (i.e. **Iteration 1 ... etc). Thanks. I have started a new question.

Comment: @Adrian ; [the above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770125/r-extracting-information-from-verbose-output-in-nlme-fit#comment76521605_44770125) saves the verbose output (in variable out)